# How to plot/save only the colorbar in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I plot only a color bar, e.g. jet from -1 to 1, in Matlab? I need to save it as an image.

Running `colorbar` also plots an empty axis next to the color bar.

Comment: Could you post the code you have at the moment?

Comment: @Acorbe Here: `colorbar`. Or `colorbar; print mybar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about this:

```
colorbar
axis off
```

### **EDIT :**

If you want to fully control the width and position of the colorbar then you can do something like:

```
fig1=figure;
left=100; bottom=100 ; width=20 ; height=500;
pos=[left bottom width height];
axis off
colorbar([0.1 0.1  0.7  0.8]);
set(fig1,'OuterPosition',pos)
```

[image]

Comment: You're right! I'll do this and then trim the image with `convert`.

Answer (score 4):

As MATLAB can only print (= save as an image) figures and `colorbar` doesn't return a figure handle, one way is to install http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig, then use:

```
colormap('jet');
cbar_handle = colorbar;
export_fig(cbar_handle, 'colorbar.png');
```

colorbar.png:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by bla, here is an answer with more adjusting possibilities. (Rep<50 means no comments possible. sry!)

```
fig1=figure;
axis off
colormap(gray(100));
caxis([-1 1]);
h = colorbar([0.1 0.1  0.8  0.7],...
  'location','Southoutside',...
  'XTick',[-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1]);
set(h,'OuterPosition',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);
```

[image: Grey Colorbar from -1 to 1]